# Dots do not change when sliding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

**When changing a slide, the dots does not change, I used a slick slider, I will attach the code and photo below. Help implement
I need that after clicking on the arrow, dots change to the next
At the moment she stays where she is.**
**Dots are implemented as span elements The buttons are built into the slider, I didn’t do it myself, I took it ready, so there were difficulties, I hope the description is enough**
[image]
[image]

**HTML**

```
    <div class="image-slider swiper">
        <div class="image-slider__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                <div class="image-slider__image">
                    <img src="img/main screen/image1.jpg" alt="main screen">                                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                <div class="image-slider__image image-slider__image2">
                    <img src="img/main screen/image2.jpg" alt="main screen">                                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                <div class="image-slider__image image-slider__image3">
                    <img src="img/main screen/image3.jpg" alt="main screen">                                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-slider__slide swiper-slide">
                <div class="image-slider__image image-slider__image4">
                    <img src="img/main screen/image4.jpg" alt="main screen">                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-span">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <h1 class="main-screen__title">Thoughtful making of space</h1>
        <a href="" class="main-screen__discover">Discover more</a>
        <div class="main-screen__discover-span"><span></span></div>
        <div class="main-screen__contact_social">
            <a href="" class="social-links">Fb</a>
            <a href="" class="social-links">In</a>
            <a href="" class="social-links">Be</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-screen__select_container">
            <div class="main-screen__select-span"></div>
            <select name="select"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'name'-->
                <option value="value1">Kiev</option>
                <option value="value2" selected>Lviv</option>
                <option value="value3">Kharkiv</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="main-screen__contact_phone-mail">
            <a href="" class="social-phone">+380983527547</a>
            <a href="" class="social-email">info@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-screen__next-project">
            <div class="next-project_s">Next Project</div>
            <div class="next-project_b">Perfect proportions</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-screen {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
            flex: 1 0 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 0;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_social {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 92%;
    left: 4.3%;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_social .social-links {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_social .social-links:first-child {
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_social .social-links:hover {
    color: #afabab;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_phone-mail {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 92%;
    left: 30.3%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-phone, .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-email {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-phone:hover, .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-email:hover {
    color: #0F0F0F;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-phone {
    padding-right: 51px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .main-screen__contact_phone-mail {
      left: 45.3%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen__contact_social {
      display: none;
    }
    .main-screen__contact_phone-mail {
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
      top: 88.3%;
    }
    .main-screen__contact_phone-mail .social-phone {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
  .main-screen__title {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 500px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 18%;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 56px;
    line-height: 68px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .main-screen__title {
      font-size: 48px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-screen__title {
      max-width: 270px;
      font-size: 44px;
      line-height: 54px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen__title {
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 39px;
      left: 5%;
    }
  }
  .main-screen__discover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.12em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .main-screen__discover-span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60.75%;
    left: 29%;
    width: 56px;
    height: 2px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .main-screen__discover-span span {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .main-screen__discover-span {
      left: 31%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 948px) {
    .main-screen__discover-span {
      left: 34%;
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen__discover {
      top: 67%;
      left: 6%;
    }
    .main-screen__discover-span {
      top: 68%;
      left: 31%;
    }
  }
  .main-screen__next-project {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 63%;
    right: -85px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  .main-screen__next-project .next-project_s {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  .main-screen__next-project .next-project_b {
    max-width: 350px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 47px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .main-screen__next-project .next-project_b {
      font-size: 32px;
      line-height: 31px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-screen__next-project {
      right: -125px;
    }
    .main-screen__next-project .next-project_b {
      max-width: 450px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen__next-project {
      top: 71%;
      right: -70px;
    }
    .main-screen__next-project .next-project_s {
      display: none;
    }
    .main-screen__next-project .next-project_b {
      max-width: 450px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 18px;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 0px;
    }
  }
  .main-screen__select_container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 91.5%;
    left: 263px;

    select{
        width: 117px;
        height: 24px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 1.15336px 1.22544px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px -0.288339px 0.0720847px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
        backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
        border-radius: 8.70783px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 13px;
        letter-spacing: 0.06em;
        color: #080808;
    }
  }
  

  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .main-screen__select_button {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #C4C4C4;
    }
    .main-screen__select_container {
      left: 25%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen__select_container {
      left: 4%;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1881px) {
    .main-screen {
      max-height: 1000px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1880px) {
    .main-screen {
      max-height: 880px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 880px) {
    .main-screen {
      max-height: 720px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .main-screen {
      max-height: 550px;
    }
  }
  .image-slider {
    position: relative;
  }
  .image-slider__image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media (min-width: 1881px) {
    .image-slider__image img {
      height: 1000px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1880px) {
    .image-slider__image img {
      height: 880px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 880px) {
    .image-slider__image img {
      height: 720px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .image-slider__image img {
      height: 500px;
    }
  }
  .image-slider .swiper-slide {
    width: auto;
  }
  .image-slider .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65%;
    top: 61%;
  }
  .image-slider .swiper-button-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 16%;
    top: 61%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .image-slider .swiper-button-prev {
      left: 16.5%;
      top: 31%;
    }
    .image-slider .swiper-button-next {
      right: 40%;
      top: 31%;
    }
  }
  .image-slider .swiper-button-prev::after, .image-slider .swiper-button-next::after {
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .swiper-span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 68%;
    top: 61%;
    width: 12.25%;
    height: 2px;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .swiper-span span {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .swiper-span span:first-child {
    left: 0px;
    height: 2px;
  }
  .swiper-span span:last-child {
    left: 54%;
    opacity: 0.32;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 612px) {
    .swiper-span {
      left: 23%;
      top: 31%;
      width: 28.25%;
    }
    .swiper-span span:first-child {
      height: 1px;
    }
  }
```

**JS**

```
New Swiper('.image-slider', {
    //Стрелки
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    },
    //количество слайдов для показа
    slidesPerView: 1.37,
    breakpoints: {
        612: {
            slidesPerView: 1.17,
        }     
    },
    //отступ между слайдами
    //spaceBetween: -19,
    //количество пролистываемых слайдов
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    //бесконечное прокручивание
    loop: true,
    //количество дублирующих слайдов
  //  loopedSlides: 3,
    //свободный режим
  //  freeMode: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'progressbar'
    },
});

new Swiper('.news-slider',{
    //количество слайдов для показа
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    //отступ между слайдами
    spaceBetween: 20,
    breakpoints: {
        769: {
            spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        1025: {
            spaceBetween: 48,
        }  
    },
    //бесконечное прокручивание
    loop: true,
        //свободный режим
    freeMode: true,
});

//select==============================================================================================

const selectButton = document.querySelector('.main-screen__select_button');
const selectList = document.querySelector('.main-screen__list');
const selectListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.main-screen__list-item');

//Клик по кнопке. Открыть, закрыть select
selectButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    selectList.classList.toggle('main-screen__list--visible');
    this.classList.add('main-screen__select_button--active');
});

//Выбор элемента списка. Запомнить выбранное значение. Закрыть дропдаун
selectListItems.forEach(function (listItem) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        selectButton.innerText = this.innerText;
        selectButton.focus();
        selectList.classList.toggle('main-screen__list--visible');
    })
})

//Клик снаружи дропдауна. Закрыть дропдаун
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target !== selectButton) {
        selectButton.classList.remove('main-screen__select_button--active');
        selectList.classList.remove('main-screen__list--visible');
    }
})
```